# Magento - How can you update the "MSRP" and the "% Off" function when a new option is selected (small, med, large,ect)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, mysqli

Here is the php code located in (template/catalog/product/price.phtml) to successfully display the MSRP and the "% Off" price of a product.

```
<?php
$msrp_mk = $_product->getMsrp();
if ($_price < $msrp_mk) { 
$_savePercent = 100 - round(($_price / $msrp_mk)*100); 
echo '$';
echo number_format((float)$msrp_mk, 2, '.', '');
echo $this->__(' You Save: ');
echo $_savePercent;
echo '%';}
?>
```

The issue is when you select from the drop-down menu. It will update the price but not the "MSRP" or the "% Off".

I believe the price is updated via product.js when changed.  We have our "small, med, large, ect" products setup as "Associated Products".

I have tried several "onchange" scripts that update the php BUT I think it updates it and just uses the old product ID selected, causing no change.

How can I update the script to use the currently selected product ID? (viewing the source and changing the currently selected option, there is no change at all in the `<option>`, `<select>` or anywhere I can find in the source.